# Same Binary search not working, one circumstance, but working in another

Tags: c, helper, cs50

Going through CS50, Pset3 and desperate for help/patience.
I'm trying to implemented `helpers.c` so that `find.c` has the correct functions to call.. However it is not connecting..

I did a separate piece I titled `testBinSearch` and that did work. With the same code.. can someone tell me why..?

```
/**
 * helpers.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 3
 *
 * Helper functions for Problem Set 3.
 */
#include <stdio.h>       
#include <cs50.h>

#include "helpers.h"

/**
 * Returns true if value is in array of n values, else false.
 */
//search(needle, haystack, size)
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)

{
    // TODO: implement a Binary searching algorithm (You are welcome to take an iterative approach (as with a loop) or a recursive approach (wherein a function calls itself).)



        //define startPoint. numberOfArrayElements(aka size) - (numberOfArrayElements(aka size) - 1) or Element[0]

       //define endPoint. numberOfArrayElements(aka size)
       int endPoint = n - 1; //element! we -1 because array start from 0th element. last element of array that is 5 elements big will thus be (total number of Elements - 1)th element.

       //define midPoint. numberOfArrayElements(aka size)/2
       int midPoint = endPoint/2; //element!

       //while loop? 
       while(n > 0)
            {   
               //if midPoint == needle, return 0
               if(values[midPoint] == value)
               {
                   return 0;
               }

               //////////(if midPoint is smaller(to the left) or larger(to the right) than needle)
               //ELSE IF midPoint > than needle(look left), keep startPoint, change endPoint element to values[midPoint - 1], define midPoint again.
               else if(values[midPoint] > value)
               {
                   endPoint = midPoint - 1;
                   midPoint = endPoint/2;
                   n = endPoint;
                   printf("mid point is more than needle\n");
               }
               //ELSE midPoint < than needle(look right), keep endPoint, change Startpoint element to values[midPoint + 1], define mindPoint again.
               else if(values[midPoint] < value)
               {
                   int startPoint = midPoint + 1;

                   //define midpoint again
                   midPoint = (endPoint + startPoint)/2;
                   n = endPoint - startPoint + 1;
                   printf("mid point is less than needle\n");
               }


            }



      printf("cued the while loop return 1\n");
      return 1;
}

/**
 * Sorts array of n values. Done with Insertion sort*
 */
void sort(int values[], int n)
{
    //declare variable
    int element;

    //number of iterations (or passes?). Skip first because first array is already sorted
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            //value of element moving into sorted portion
            element = values[i];

            //declare variable
            int j = 0;

            //index into the unsorted portion
            j = i;

            //iterate sorted portion from right to left while sorted portion is greater than 'Element' being compared in this iteration of i.
            //basically, it stops this loop once the 'Element' is placed to the left of all greater&&sorted numbers.
            while(j > 0 && values[j - 1] > element)
            {
                //shift all sorted positions to the right 
                values[j] = values[j - 1];

                // this enables the loop to move left through the sorted portion
                j = j - 1; 

            }

            //insert temp holder value into the position which is now empty because all sorted&&greater number are to the right of 'Element'
            values[j] = element;

        }


        for(int k = 0; k < n; k++)
         //print to check
            {
                printf("{%i}<-- number in %i-th array (sorted)\n", values[k], k);

            }
}
```

Here is the `find.c` code:

```
/**
 * find.c
 *
 * Computer Science 50
 * Problem Set 3
 *
 * Prompts user for as many as MAX values until EOF is reached, 
 * then proceeds to search that "haystack" of values for given needle.
 *
 * Usage: ./find needle
 *
 * where needle is the value to find in a haystack of values
 */

#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "helpers.h"

// maximum amount of hay
const int MAX = 65536;

int main(int argc, string argv[])
{
    // ensure proper usage
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./find needle\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // remember needle
    int needle = atoi(argv[1]);

    // fill haystack
    int size;
    int haystack[MAX];
    for (size = 0; size < MAX; size++)
    {
        // wait for hay until EOF
        printf("\nhaystack[%i] = ", size);
        int straw = GetInt();
        if (straw == INT_MAX)
        {
            break;
        }

        // add hay to stack
        haystack[size] = straw;
    }
    printf("\n");

    // sort the haystack
    sort(haystack, size);

    // try to find needle in haystack
    if (search(needle, haystack, size))
    {
        printf("\nFound needle in haystack!\n\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nDidn't find needle in haystack.\n\n");
        return 1;
    }

}
```

And finally, here's the code that worked(or at least it seems to work) separately when I keyed them all in one file... titled `testBinSearch` below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

void sort(int array[], int NumberOfElements);
bool search(int value, int values[], int n);

int main(void)


{
    //decalre variable
    int NumberOfElements;

    printf("how many Element would you like in this array?\n");
    NumberOfElements = GetInt();

    //declare variable for array
    int array[NumberOfElements];


    for(int i = 0; i < NumberOfElements; i++)
        {
            printf("alright, please key in value of each element\n");
            array[i] = GetInt();
        }

    sort(array, NumberOfElements);

    for (int i = 0; i < NumberOfElements; i++)
        {
            printf("alright, here is your array sorted, element %i is %i\n", i, array[i]);
        }

    printf("value ot search for?\n");
    int value = GetInt();
    search(value, array, NumberOfElements);
}


//----------
void sort(int array[], int NumberOfElements)
{
    //declare variable
    int element;

    //number of iterations (or passes?). Skip first because first array is already sorted
    for (int i = 1; i < NumberOfElements; i++)
        {
            //value of element moving into sorted portion
            element = array[i];

            //declare variable
            int j = 0;

            //index into the unsorted portion
            j = i;

            //iterate sorted portion from right to left while sorted portion is greater than 'Element' being compared in this iteration of i.
            //basically, it stops this loop once the 'Element' is placed to the left of all greater&&sorted numbers.
            while(j > 0 && array[j - 1] > element)
            {
                //shift all sorted positions to the right 
                array[j] = array [j - 1];

                // this enables the loop to move left through the sorted portion
                j = j - 1; 

            }

            //insert temp holder value into the position which is now empty because all sorted&&greater number are to the right of 'Element'
            array[j] = element;

        }

}

//--------------
bool search(int value, int values[], int n)

{
    // TODO: implement a Binary searching algorithm (You are welcome to take an iterative approach (as with a loop) or a recursive approach (wherein a function calls itself).)

    //variables declaration
    //int startPoint;
    //int endPoint;
    //int midPoint;

        //define startPoint. numberOfArrayElements(aka size) - (numberOfArrayElements(aka size) - 1) or Element[0]

       //define endPoint. numberOfArrayElements(aka size)
       int endPoint = n - 1; //element!

       //define midPoint. numberOfArrayElements(aka size)/2
       int midPoint = endPoint/2; //element!

       //while loop? 
       while(n > 0)
            {   
               //if midPoint == needle, return 0
               if(values[midPoint] == value)
               {
                   printf("found it!\n");
                   return 0;
               }

               //////////(if midPoint is smaller(to the left) or larger(to the right) than needle)
               //ELSE IF midPoint > than needle(look left), keep startPoint, change endPoint element to values[midPoint - 1], define midPoint again.
               else if(values[midPoint] > value)
               {
                   endPoint = midPoint - 1;
                   midPoint = endPoint/2;
                   n = endPoint;
               }
               //ELSE midPoint < than needle(look right), keep endPoint, change Startpoint element to values[midPoint + 1], define mindPoint again.
               else if(values[midPoint] < value)
               {
                   int startPoint = midPoint + 1;

                   //define midpoint again
                   midPoint = (endPoint + startPoint)/2;
                   n = endPoint - startPoint + 1;
               }


            }


      printf("could not find it\n");
      return 1;
}
```

Can someone help me out and tell me where I went wrong? I came up with the code and copied it right over, but one worked(`testBinSearch`) and one didn't(`helpers.c`).. ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Note that an acidic test of a binary search function creates an array with N entries (for various values of N, say 1 .. 129), and loads an array D with values `D[n] = n * 2;` for n in 0 .. N-1 (your sorted array of data), and then checks that the search for a value V is correct for every value from -1 .. 2N-1.  For the odd values, the search should fail; for the even values, it should find the correct value (which your test can verify, of course).  Methinks your code wouldn't pass that sort of test.  Note that the proposed test harness doesn't require user interaction, so it can run flat out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this covers the whole problem but anyway...

This calculation

```
midPoint = endPoint/2;
```

is wrong.

Assume you have an array of 100 elements. The code may bring you to a situation where you look at index 75 to 99 with midpoint in between (e.g. 87), i.e. you have taken the `smaller than` path a couple of times.

Now if you take the `greater than` part you calculate a midpoint (e.g. 43) being outside the range of interest

Further, the startpoint variable is not to be a variable inside the `smaller than` case. It must be at the same level as endpoint. In each loop you must change either startpoint **or** endpoint. Calculation of midpoint shall always depend on both startpoint and endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for that! I managed to sort it all out. @olaf sorry I will definitely be more careful next time. thanks for the great help here guys, really love that there's such a helpful community around :D